# Image Javascript Resize Big to Small vice versa

Tags: javascript, image, resize

I'm creating my first JavaScript code and and can't quite figure out something. An image has to become enlarged once clicked and minimized if clicked again. I applied a class that makes it small initially and can successfully make the image large. The thing is, when I use the `if` statement, it doesn't revert back to small. It actually messes up everything and doesn't even enlarge anymore. The code makes sense to me, but obviously I'm missing something crucial. Below is my code, any help would be appreciated.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

    thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
        thumbnailElement.className = "";

        if (thumbnailElement.className == "") {
            thumbnailElement.className = "small";
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `classList.toggle`

```js
var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");

thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
  thumbnailElement.classList.toggle('toggleSize')
});
```

```css
.imgContainer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.toggleSize {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="smart_thumbnail" class="imgContainer">

  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9198/nature-sky-twilight-grass-9198.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">

</div>
```

Comment: Just for "beautiful" purposes, you can also add a `transition-duration: 1s;` to `toggleSize` class, just to let it smooth, if you want it, of course.

Comment: yeah, I know, actually my comment was more to the asker, if he wants, because the answer itself is what you posted originally. :)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses! I like tip for the transition. Unfortunately, I don't think I can use this method as the point of the training is to learn how to use the IF and ELSE statements to switch between class="small" and class="". Class"" being it removes the small property.